# what is EditorialMarkerFactory.?

Tags: solr, document, config

What is ***EditorialMarkerFactory*** in solr.?
How it used in ***DocumentTransformer***...?
For what **scenarios** ***we have to use EditorialMarkerFactory*** in our application...  ?
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DocTransformers) you can read why and how it is used. It says

> EditorialMarkerFactory is used to mark items that have been editorially boosted by the QueryElevationComponent so that an application has the option of treating them specially

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the EditorialMarkerFactory with solr 4.0 final and it wouldn't work. The error was class not found.

I changed the class to ElevatedMarkerFactory in the solrconfig.xml file and it started working. Solr needs to update the wiki and the default solrconfig.xml file